# WP site makes mobile browser crash for high memory usage

Tags: theme-development, javascript, memory, framework

I have this site: http://theguiltycode.com 
It uses foundation as a theme and is hosted in bluehost. I can load the site without much problem in desktop browsers, but in mobile the site reloads like 3 times and an error appears: A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded. —Safari, iOS— or Aw, Snap! in Chrome —also for iOS—

Also, if I try to check the site via GTMetrix it says that the browser run out of memory.

I have tried deactivating all the plugins —the error persists— and I can't check the site in the web inspector of safari because it closes immediately. I don't know how to debug this, any suggestions? Of course, disabling JavaScript solves the problem...

Comment: First of all: page size almost **6MB** and **almost 1200 requests**!? This will hit any device like a truck. Secondly, it's hard to tell anything when I get almost 300 errors. You'll need to fix them before we can tell you anything remotely useful.

Answer (score -1):

Your page has almost 500 requests and 5mb of data to download – Are you confident with changing the template? Look at a browser console and check all the errors that show. Most of the time, it's external JS that ruins these kind of experiences – advertising, tracking etc. Try to be conservative with your choices of scripts.

Finally, I would consider using a caching plugin to try and concat the JS files together. My favourite caching wp plugin at the moment is [WP Rocket](http://wp-rocket.me/)

Comment: Using a cache plugin is not a solution, it simply will hide what is actually wrong. You should really start at looking what is causing the huge mount of queries, and sort that out first. Also, there is a huge amount of errors that **MUST** be sorted out first. When everything is sorted, yes, then a cache plugin would work nicely